# Shields of Judah

Tags: 1-kings, 2-kings, 2-chronicles, 1-chronicles

1 Kings 14:27 and 2 Chronicles 12:10 state that King Rehoboam made bronze shields to replace the golden ones that King David had made because the golden ones were taken away.

In 2 Kings 11:10 and 2 Chronicles 23:9, it states that Jehoida gave the captains the shields of King David.

2 Chronicles 12:10:

> and King Rehoboam made in their place shields of bronze and committed
>   them to the hands of the officers of the guard, who kept the door of
>   the king’s house.

2 Chronicles 23:9:

> And Jehoiada the priest gave to the captains the spears and the large
>   and small shields that had been King David’s, which were in the house
>   of God.

Are these two different sets of shields?  Perhaps these passages are referring to a royal insignia of King David?  If I'm not mistaken, Solomon made golden shields that were stored in the Place of the Forest of Lebanon (2 Chron 9:16).  But these shields were taken by Shishak (2 Chron 12:9).  Perhaps someone can help me sort out my confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Shelatim of David and the Magginot and Tsinnah of Solomon

I think the source of confusion is mixing the different words translated as "small shield": *magen* and *shelet*.

### The mysterious shelet

*shelet* only appears 7 time in the OT and there is some doubt as to whether it refers to a small circular shield or a quiver.

Here it NIDOTT:

> ANE This word is of rather obscure etymology but is likely connected
> with a verbal root attested in Akk. (šalāṭu) and Arab. (salaṭa). The
> exact nuance of this term escapes us, so it is safest to translate
> generically as “shield.”
>
> OT The term occurs only 7× in the OT, 3× with מָגֵן (2 Chron 23:9;
> Song of Songs 4:4; Ezek 27:11). In all other cases, שֶׁלֶט refers to
> the military weapon and is never used in a metaphorical sense for
> God’s protection (see 2 Sam 8:7 = 1 Chron 18:7). The word is often
> used in contexts where shields are placed on ornamental display. That
> the word means “shield” is certain in a passage like Song of Songs
> 4:4, where the parallelism clearly intends a near synonym of a
> narrower meaning to מָגֵן, the most common term for shield. However,
> Borger (1972) has marshaled evidence from the versions and cognates
> that the word means “quiver” in Jer 51:11. Thus, NRSV so renders in
> that and other passages (cf. Ezek 27:11). For full discussion of the
> issue see Holladay (422–23).
> VanGemeren, W. (Ed.). (1997). *New international dictionary of Old Testament theology & exegesis* (Vol. 4, p. 125). Grand Rapids, MI: Zondervan Publishing House.

Whatever the *shelatim* were, David captured an unspecified number of gold shelatim from the Syrians, together with a large amount of bronze, and carried these back to Jerusalem. See 2 Sam 8.7 and mirrored in 1 Chron 18.7

Judah now has an unknown number of gold shelatim and a lot of bronze.

### Magen and Tsinnah

*magen* is widely used in the Old Testament to mean "shield" (that you carry).

*tsinnah* is a standing shield (covers from head to foot). It only appears twice in the OT.

- Solomon *made* 200 gold *tsinnah* and 300 gold *maginnim* as described in 1 Ki 10.16-17 and paralleled in 2 Chron 9.15-16.
- The 300 gold *magginim* of Solomon were taken by Shishak as described in 1 Ki 14.25-27 and paralleled in 2 Chron 12.9-10. In the same passage, Rehoboam replaces the maginnim with versions made of bronze. No mention is made of the 200 large standing shields -- were they taken? Where they replaced? The text doesn't say and they are not mentioned again.

> It happened in the fifth year of King Rehoboam that Shishak the king
> of Egypt came up against Jerusalem, and he took the treasures of the
> house of Yahweh, and he took all the treasures of the king’s house. He
> took the small gold shields [maginne] that Solomon had made, so King Rehoboam
> made small copper shields [maginne] in place of them and entrusted them to the
> commanders of the royal guard who keep the doorway of the king’s
> house.

Thus Isreal is missing its 300 gold *magginim*, which have been replaced with newly created bronze versions, but Israel still has an unspecified number of gold *shelatim* that David captured frm Syria, and may or may not have the 200 gold *tsinnah* that Solomon made.

In 2 Chron 23.9, Jehoida gives the 300 (bronze) [maginnot] made by Rehoboam and the unspecified number of gold shelatim that belonged to David, and distributed them to the commanders of the hundreds:

> And Jehoiada the priest gave the spears and the large shields
> [maginnot] and small shields [shelatim] that had belonged to King
> David that were in the house of God to the commanders of hundreds.

Comment: Wow, this is very interesting.  thanks!